# Rows in tableViewCell changes their places when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I've a `tableView` with `myCustomCell` in it.

This cell includes a **button** and **progress view**. By clicking button file downloading is starting and progress view showing downloading progress. Everything is great except the moment when I'm scrolling `tableView` after download started in any cell - the progress view is showing in other cell, not those one I clicked on first. For example, if I clicked on first cell and scrolled down a bit - the first cell which will be the first after scrolling stopped will show progress of downloading file. If I start 2 or more downloads, their both changes their places.

Here is a short video to display the problem: https://youtu.be/BTtU94ODbBI

(`cell` can change it place randomly and many times in `tableView`, and also just `progress view` can move to another cell)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

the tableview is delegating to you, the view controller, to provide a cell for the tableview to render.

When that cell goes off screen, it is fair game to be recycled and reused in this method.
 Your problem stems from the recycled cell still keeping its previous state.

To stop this behaviour, each time you create (or fetch) a cell in this function, hide/reset any progress updates. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should get a clean cell each time it asks for one, and you should configure it only before presenting it.

In your case, `myCustomCell` could have a method `- (void) clean;` that sets the progressView to hidden, the title to `@""` etc. Call this as soon as `cell` is created and you are good to go

Comment: You don't need to define a new method - UITableViewCell already has a method `prepareForReuse` that you can implement in your custom cell subclass.

Comment: I've added an downloading boolean and pVal double which tells if file is downloading and if yes downloading progress stores in pVal. In cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm showing all progress view and hide download button if downloading boolean is true. In did not resolve the problem :/